# create table prog (S_No int ,Prog_Name char(20),coll_id int,Add constrain fr_key FOREIGN KEY(S_

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I cannot add constraints in SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> create table prog (S_No int ,
  2  Prog_Name char(20),coll_id int,
  3  ADD constrain fr_key FOREIGN KEY(S_No) references stud(reg));
**ADD constrain fr_key FOREIGN KEY(S_No) references stud(reg))
***
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Comment: Add contrainT? You might want to give the FK a more descriptive, and unique name, e.g. `FK_PROG_STUD`

Comment: I don't have any idea about index in sql [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

Comment: @user3720376: don't use w3schools as a reference. It's full of errors. Use the official Oracle manual instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ADD` for a constraint inside the `CREATE TABLE` statement (that's only valid in an `alter table` statement). And it should be `constraint` not `constrain`

```
create table prog 
(
  S_No int,
  Prog_Name char(20),
  coll_id int,
  constraint fr_key FOREIGN KEY(S_No) references stud(reg)
);
```

The above assumes that the table `stud` is already created and has a primary key with the column `reg` defined.

For a full description on the syntax please see the manual: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52184

I'm also very certain that you do **not** want to use `char` but `varchar` (which is the same as `varchar2`) instead